# unable to login wordpress user which i register

Tags: php, wordpress

I am authenticating the  user to approve first  with the  function

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', function($user) {

  if (get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_flag', true) == 'active') 
  {
    return $user;
  }
  return new WP_Error('Account Not Active...');
}, 10, 2, 0);
```

By default user registered as subscriber  and i get the password in mail for registers user  and its working  fine if  i am not using this authenticating function but with this i unable to login to word-press  i mathc the  meta value for user and approve that from admin

Every time i try to login with user give me data not received and back to login.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work this way, if you want to an extra check to the wp_authenticate_user filter you need to go

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'my_custom_function_name', 10, 2);
```

Where `my_custom_function_name` is the name of your custom function

So, you need to put your function in

```
function my_custom_function_name($user, $password){
    if (get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_flag', true) == 'active') {
        return $user;
    }

    return new WP_Error('Account Not Active...');
}
```

Comment: According to [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) anonymous functions _are_ allowed as the second parameter of `add_filter`.

Comment: Yeah, but if he has a lower version of PHP < 5.3 it won't work :(